# ACSL / Fortran printing variable values in strings like a printf when it shouldn't?

Tags: printf

I'm currently trying to learn ACSL, a precompiled language for Fortran, and have found that when trying to debug by outputting values to the screen to follow the values, this language will actually dump the value in place of the string, as would happen in a printf. Does anyone know what's happening here?

```
o = 5
write(*,*) 'o=',o
print *, 'o=',o
```

will output:

```
5=5
```

Anyone know how to stop this?

Comment: I've never heard of ACSL, and the Wikipedia disambiguation page doesn't have an obvious match.  Is it this one? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Continuous_Simulation_Language

Comment: I think you need to provide more info about ACSL. Is it Advanced Continuous Simulation Language? I found some info about it on Wikipedia. The fact that this language translator just translates models into C or FORTRAN source code doesn't make your question a Fortran question. If I understand correctly the piece of code is  ACSL source code and not Fortran one. So you should probably retag your question.

Comment: Yes, it is Advanced Continuous Simulation Language, the documentation is pretty sparse, but supposedly the majority of it is largely similar to Fortran, so I was hoping that the issues I'm having with print output were more correlated with the Fortran aspect. I would change the Tags, however ACSL is not an existing tag, and adding new tags requires 200 rep.

Comment: According to Wikipedia article there are only two alive ACSL implementations. Both are closed source, commercial, without easily accessible trial versions. Damn! :( This fact together with the fact that ACSL is special-purpose language decreases the chances to get help significantly.

Comment: Yes, I've been finding that it is extremely obscure, and as far as I can tell the only available instructions are the manuals that come directly from the manufacturers, which are extremely cryptic (very little useful syntax information is provided, just a long list of available functions and a mention that "the language is very similar to Fortran", but it's even somewhat unclear which Fortran they're talking about, though it's likely Fortran 77). Hopefully just fiddling with it long enough will give me an idea of how to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some time working with the ACSL language, I never did actually find a way to escape output variable names. Turns out this particular ACSL interpreter went through C program that would then interpret the ACSL output, which was apparently the cause of the issue. I'm cleaning out some of my unanswered questions, and won't delete this question because I do not want to remove any of what little information about this language does exist out there.